# Pandas Group by having

Tags: pandas

I'm learning pandas and I have this problem :

I have a dataframe with columns A, B, C, D, E

I want to exprim the following sql to the equivalent in pandas :

```
select A, B, sum(C), sum (D), sum(E)
from T
group by A
having sum(A,B,C) > 0
```

I try this :

```
df.groupby(A).filter([C,D,E].sum() > 0).agg(sum(C),sum(D),sum(E))
```

But doesn't work

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you please provide a [mre] (input dataset and matching expected output)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to filter the rows with B+C+D>0, group by A and sum each of the C/D/E columns:

```
df[df[['A', 'B', 'C']].sum(axis=1)>0].groupby('A')[['C', 'D', 'E']].sum()
```

Or if you want to filter after the aggregation:

```
(df.groupby(['A', 'B'], as_index=False)[['C', 'D', 'E']].sum()
   .loc[lambda x: x[['A', 'B', 'C']].sum(axis=1)>0]
)
```

Comment: Thanks for u answer, I thought that the “Having” clause is used to filter the record from the groups based on the specified condition. but here it seem that you use the clause where, perhaps I miss some thing!

Comment: @ssaf that's why I asked for clarification, can you provide a example dataset and the matching expected output?